# Charging laptop via laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

Can I charge my HP Omnibook 4150 off my HP Pavilion notebook by connecting USB

to USB, or any other connection, as I don't have a charger for the Omnibook?

Ive tried googling.

Comment: HP will sell you a charger.  You might be able to find a third party replacement, or a used one on eBay, and save a little money.

Answer (score 3):

Your laptop expects a higher voltage input, often 19 volts, than a USB provides (5vdc) and expects it to be delivered to a different location in the circuit.

Your USB port would be damaged if sufficient power was applied to the computer to charge the battery, which is also a higher voltage than USB allows.

Comment: Just to add, some devices can be charged through a USB port, but according to the manual, the 4150 isn't capable of that.  Those devices that can, negotiate for a high supply current, which would not work with the Pavilion USB port.  So even for a device that could charge through the USB port, it would take forever, and you would need to have it powered off so that it wasn't trying to operate on the minimal current coming from the USB port.